# Can I use Resources.getSystem()?

Tags: android

I want to initialize `static final String[]` variable from `string.xml`.
So I found the solution `Resources.getSystem()` but, I'm worried to use it.

This is my code before use it.

```
public enum Type {
    STUDENT, TEACHER, PARENT, GRADUATE, OTHERS;

    public static final int[] typeNamesRes = new int[] {
        R.string.student,
        R.string.teacher,
        R.string.parent,
        R.string.graduate,
        R.string.others;
    };
    public static final String[] typeNames= new String[typeNamesRes.length];

    public static init(Context context) {
        for (int i=0; i<typeNamesRes.length; i++) {
            typeNames[i] = context.getString(typeNamesRes[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return typeNames[ordinal()];
    }
}
```

But, this code must call `init` method.
I think this is not good way.
Because this will occur the error when didn't call `init` method (by mistake)

So I use `Resources.getSystem()`.

```
public enum Type {
    STUDENT, TEACHER, PARENT, GRADUATE, OTHERS;

    public static final String[] typeNames = new String[] {
        Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.student),
        Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.teacher),
        Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.parent),
        Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.graduate),
        Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.others);
    };

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return typeNames[ordinal()];
    }
}
```

But, I think `Resources.getSystem()` may be not safe.
I worried about It return `null` or `invalid Resources`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The system `Resources` will not have your app's `Resources`. Your second code block will throw a `Resources$NotFoundException`.

Comment: @MikeM. But, when I use to get DP and SP (Resources.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density, scaledDensity) is working.

Comment: @MikeM. Because getDisplayMetrics is not app's Resources?

Comment: Right, because those are system resources not specific to your app.

Comment: @MikeM. Then it is fine to use it to get DP and SP?

Comment: Yes. But you can't use it to get strings, colors, drawables, etc. that are in your app.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @MikeM. Ah! then... My first solution (use `init` method) is fine?  Which is better of use `getName(Context context)` instead of `toString()` or use `init(Context context)` and `toString()`

Comment: I think your `init()` method is fine.

Comment: @MikeM. It has been very helpful. I really really appreciate it.